# Short story: super computers save humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story about a super computer (USA). 
The computer (big one) is talking to the captain, the news is that there are less and less children born on Earth. 
They ask the computer if the Russians have something to do with this, after a time the computer say no. Something is coming from the moon.
The USA send the captain to the moon, the Russians send a female cosmonaut to the moon as well.

After one month they come back, and they tell that they have escaped from a alien base on the moon and that the beam is destroyed.

Now again are children born.

When the captain goes to talk to the computer he remembers what really happened on the moon, he and the Russian female astronaut had a good time there they; felt in love.

The man wants to meet the woman but the computer tells him she is already on the way to him.

It seems that both supercomputers came up with same plan to make a common enemy.

Any idea who has written this story.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["Honeymoon in Hell"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55213), a novelette by [Fredric Brown](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55213); first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, November 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58611+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1950-11/Galaxy_1950_11#page/n5/mode/2up) (click [here](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v01n02_1950-11) for download options), as is the [*X Minus One*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne56-12-26081HoneymoonInHell.mp3) radio adaptation (no. 79, from December 26, 1956).

The ISFDB has this plot synopsis:

> No more male children are born in Earth. The officials suspect an alien plot, and they draft two spacepilots, one male from US, and another a female from USSR to fly to the moon and test if it would be possible to conceive a male child there. And the most important part of that plan is that they should get married as soon as possible. And they get a case whiskey to make things smoother.

Comment: Thanks that was the story and also thanks for the link X minus one.